# Different footer versions in Community Builder

Tags: community, community-builder

I need to create a different footer for one of our page. The only difference is the disclaimer language. How is this achieved? Currently, the footer is shared throughout the site.

Comment: Are you using a lightning or VF + tabs community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to check the "Override the default theme layout for this page" button which is located all the way down on the Page Properties tab pane.

Comment: please remember to mark your answer as accepted so it comes out of the list of unanswered questions.